# PHP / JAVA: Redirection / detection?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I checked this website: http://summe7.webnode.fr/ and this is redirecting to another site if users visit by mobile. If they visit by PC, Mozilla, Chrome, Opera etc then nothing happens.

I checked the source and noticed this code snippet:

```
<script src='http://69videos.site/1375621'></script>
```

Inside this I found this:

```
var _0xa410=["http://69videos.site/mobil.php","replace","location"];    top[_0xa410[2]][_0xa410[1]](_0xa410[0])
```

I try replicate this but my webnode site redirects Desktop browsers and Mobile.

I want to just redirect users using mobile and not browsers like his site mentioned above.

Sorry for my bad english, it is not my main language.

What i can do to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Wilson, welcome to SO. Please try to format your questions correctly so that others can help you more easily. Pleae take also a moment to look into this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have not visited the site you have linked in the question, but basically what you need to do is this:

```
function isUserOnMobile(){
   // return true or false based on whatever you detect.
   // This detection will almost certainly take place by examining user-agent
}

function doRedirect(GoToUrl){
    window.location.replace(GoToUrl);
}

window.onload = function(){
     var mobileVersionUrl = "https://mobile.example.com/";
     if(isUserOnMobile()){
          doRedirect(mobileVersionUrl);
     }
}
```

As for how you detect if the device is mobile, things get a little bit tricky there because a user can spoof user-agents and more importantly, you may not know every single mobile device user-agent. However, for the most part, you can write your mobile detection like the following:

```
function isUserOnMobile(){
 var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
}
```

That code comes from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/2694511

Essentially, that long code is just checking for characteristics in the user-agent to detect if a device appears to be a mobile phone or tablet.

Comment: hi sir, thanks for reply... i try use this code in webnode.com and is not redirecting... so i need you guys help me with this code that i posted above, please check the site. for god sake. its important for me